# jQuery bind event on dynamic element for focus, keypress, keydown, keyup didn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind, live

```
<div id="t1" contenteditable="true" style="width: 400px; height: 200px;">
    <ul>
        <li style="list-style-type: none;">Apple</li>
    </ul>
</div>    <span id="dd"></span>

<script>
$(function () {
    event.returnValue = false;
    $('#t1>ul').on("click", 'li', function () {
        utility.test(this);
    });
});

var utility = {
    test: function (elem) {
        var $this = $(elem);
        $('#dd').html($this.html());
        if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

above code is work fine, but if I change bind event from click to keydown as below

```
$('#t1>ul').on("keydown", 'li', function () {
```

then it's didn't work.
I am using jQuery version 1.9.1, and try using .live for version 1.8.3, but still didn't work.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tag with the `contenteditable` flag will capture and emit the `keydown` event, not content within it. Simply put, your `<li>` is not emitting the `keydown` event.

Comment: I need the flag for editing my content, is there are any solution for this case?

Comment: What are you looking to do after the event occurs? Based on the code in hand, it appears you might be looking to test the validity of the changes? If so, you could monitor `$("#t1")` for the `keydown` event, and then check its children, but it all largely depends on what you're exactly looking to accomplish after `keydown` event.

Comment: What I want is made indent and put costume symbol(**That is Chinese words 一、二、三 etc.**) before a line/new line. just like a list auto numbering.So I need to check and reassign number if user delete some row.

Comment: I think that would involve grabbing the `html` value of `#t1` and doing some processing against it on each keystroke, replacing the content of `#t1` on each pass. It would become rather expensive, I must admit.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just initially select the li?

```
$('#t1 li').on("keydown", function () {
    alert('You are typing');
    utility.test(this);
});
```

Comment: I tried, but it's can't bind on new create element. Thanks for you reply.